# web2py linking to CSS

Tags: python, web2py

I'm learning web2py 1.98.2, so the question is very basic. In static/css folder I created basic.css file with the following content:

```
.auth_navbar {
  top: 0px;
  float: right;
  padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px; 
}
```

In layout.html I have:

```
<head>
  ...
  {{response.files.append(URL('static','css/base.css'))}}
  ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  {{try:}}{{=auth.navbar(action=URL('default','user'))}}{{except:pass}} 
  ...
</body>
```

Controller default.py has very simple code:

```
def index(): return dict(message="hello people")
```

And, lastly, default/index.html looks like:

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
<h2>This is the default/index.html template</h2>
{{#=BEAUTIFY(response._vars)}}
```

So, I run the app and index.html is displayed as expected. However, CSS is not working.
I expected the following line in the page source:

```
<link href="/welcome/static/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

but it's not there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{response.files.append(URL('static','css/base.css'))}}
```

The above line simply adds base.css to the response.files list. The `<link>` tag is generated by the web2py_ajax.html template, which is included in the default layout.html. So, you need to make sure that web2py_ajax.html is also included in your layout.html, and that base.css is added to response.files *before* that. So:

```
{{response.files.append(URL('static','css/base.css'))}}
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
```

Note, your first sentence refers to basic.css, but your code refers to base.css -- make sure you're using the right filename (web2py comes with its own base.css).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you left out:

```
{{include}}
```

In the body tags of your layout.html.

Comment: I made a minor edit to your answer so that it qualifies as an answer (asking for clarification shouldn't happen in answers).